# Code First Entity Framework doesn't create one to many relationship

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first, code-first

So I have a class (Article) That is supposed to have a one-to-many relationship with another class (Category):

```
public class Article
{
  [Key]
  public int ArticleId { get; set;}

  public virtual List<Category> Categories { get; set; }
}

public class Category
{
  [Key]
  public int Id { get; set;}

  public string Caption { get; set;
}
```

When I had Code First build the Database, it generated Category having a one-to-one relationship with Article. This results in the the Category only being related to a single Article. Dropping and recreating the database still generates the issue. Any idea on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Toss the `Article` constructor; for EF to effectively work its magic, change `public List...`  to `public virtual List...`; also, create a `[Key]` for Article - right now the SQL equivalent is creating a table with one column that is a foreign key.

Comment: Tried this, but the database stayed the same and an add-migration call generated a blank file.

Comment: Which database is this? SQL Server shouldn't have any problem with this.

Comment: little confusion. does article has many categories, or category has many articles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1)** If your `Article` has many `Category`, but `Categories` has only one `Article`:

```
public class Article{
    private ICollection<Category> _CategoryList;
    public int ArticleId { get; set;}
    public virtual ICollection<Category> CategoryList {
        get { return _CategoryList = _CategoryList?? new HashSet<Category>(); }
        set { _CategoryList= value; }
    }
}

public class Category{
    public int Id { get; set;}
    public string Caption { get; set;}
    public Article Article { get; set;}
}
```

This sounds little inlogical for me.

**2)** If your `Category` has many `Article`, and `Article` has only one `Category`:

```
public class Article{
    public int ArticleId { get; set;}
    public Category Category { get; set;}
}

public class Category{
    private ICollection<Article> _ArticleList;
    public int Id { get; set;}
    public string Caption { get; set;}
    public virtual ICollection<Article> ArticleList {
        get { return _ArticleList= _ArticleList?? new HashSet<Article>(); }
        set { _ArticleList= value; }
    }
}
```

Note, you do not need `[Key]` in case there is keyword `Id` in the property name. EF treats the property as `Key` automatically.